# How to achieve object re-usability in C# using Dictionary

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary

This is my code. Problem is explained bellow. What I'm trying to do is implement hash map object re-usability in Java to C# using dictionary.

**Form 1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 bb = (Form2)UiFac.loadUi();
    }
}
```

**Form 2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    int a = 1;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(a.ToString());
        a++;
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.ExitThread();
    }

    public Form2 getForm2()
    {
        return this;
    }
}
```

and the **UiFac** class

```
public class UiFac
{
    public enum UiName
    {
        LOGIN,
        HOME
    }
    static Dictionary<UiName,Form> map = new Dictionary<UiName, Form>();

    public static Form loadUi()
    {
        Form theForm;
        map.TryGetValue(UiName.HOME, out theForm);
        if (shit == null)
        {
            Form2 bb = new Form2();
            Console.WriteLine("Inside if " + bb.GetHashCode());
            map.Add(UiName.HOME, bb);
            bb.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            map.TryGetValue(UiName.HOME,out theForm);
            Console.WriteLine("Inside else " + shit.GetHashCode());
            Form2 ff = (Form2)theForm;
            ff = ff.getForm2();
            ff.Show();
        }
        return theForm;
    }
}
```

I did this using Hash Maps in java and it works perfectly. Then I got the need to do the same using C#. When I press `Button1` in Form1 for the fist time `Form2` loads. But when I close it and again press `Button1` in `Form1` it throws `System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.Windows.Forms.dll`

What am I missing?

thank you!

Comment: Could it be that when you "close" Form2 it actually closes the form (disposes of it, makes it go away, object no longer good) ?

Comment: @Dweeberlyv does the object gets destroyed when I close it? if not object address is saved in the Dictionary. So why can't I call Show() method?

Comment: @KumarathungaMunidasa  Why do you want to reuse Form2?  If it's because you don't want all the data to reset, then you should hide it instead of close it.  If it's because you think there's some performance benefit, then don't bother.  It's not worth it.

Comment: When you close a form (red X), the form gets destroyed.  Think about it this way if you had only one form in a application and you closed it would you want it to hang around?  You can either make the form a dialog (ShowDialog) or override the close behavior (so the object isn't disposed).

Comment: @SamIam well I can hide and show. But I really wanna solve this. If it's working in java then there should be a way in C#. I want to know what it is.

Comment: Do not try to recreate the exact same behavior in c#, these are just two different languages with different behaviors!

Comment: @KumarathungaMunidasa solve what?  What is your end goal? Why do you want to reuse the Form?

Comment: @Dweeberly So the answer is I can't use what I did in java in C#?

Comment: @SamIam well let's say for education! Is there a way?

Comment: Yes, different languages and different frameworks (Swing / WinForms) have different behaviors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `Close()` on a form it will be disposed eventually by the framework. Use the `Hide()` method instead.

From [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.closing(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks):

> When a form is closed, all resources created within the object are released and the form is disposed.

As NightOwl stated in the comment I advice you when the application is closed you loop trough the dictionary and close or dispose all the forms present to avoid resource leaks. You can do that by implementing the [`IDispose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) interface in the `UiFac` class and call `Dispose` on all forms in the collection:

```
public sealed class UiFac : IDisposable
{
    ...

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Call dispose on all forms
    }
}
```

On closing `Form1` call `UiFac.Dispose();`

Comment: Thank you! I overrode the close button and hid the form

Comment: It might also be a good idea to point out that the `UiFac` class should implement `IDisposable.Dispose()` so it can loop through the `map`, dispose the instances, and then clear the `map`. The caller of `UiFac` is responsible for calling `Dispose()` on it, otherwise those forms may cause a resource leak.

Comment: @KumarathungaMunidasa - Peter updated the answer with an example already. Have a look at [Implementing a Dispose method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) for complete details. Do note that static variables and `IDisposable` don't blend together very easily - it might make more sense to use instance variables.